# PHP not being called in contact form when submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Before this is marked as a duplicate please actually read what I have to say. It is not a matter of the email is not being sent, the PHP is not actually being called when the submit button is clicked.

Code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "reviews@itssimplytech.co.uk";
    $subject = "Simply Tech Contact Form";
    $headers = 'From: '$email"\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '$email"\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers) or die("Error!");  
    echo "Thank You!";
    ?>
    <a data-scroll href="#contact"></a>
    <?php
}
?>
<form class="contact-form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea rows="5" name="message" placeholder="Say Something..." required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit">
</form> <!--  /.contact-form  -->
```

When the form is submitted the page just refreshes and the form is cleared but I don't think it is calling the PHP since no email is sent and no messages are displayed nor does it scroll back down to contact. Which this line should make it do.

```
<a data-scroll href="#contact"></a>
```

Comment: @chris85 just edited the original post explaining that :p

Comment: Do basic debugging. Add `print_r($_POST)`, what `$_POST` values are shown? Does your server support PHP? Does `echo "Hello world";` work? It's possible that there's an underlying server issue with the `mail()` function as well.

Comment: @kirk,, if the server didn't support php OP would be seeing their own code

Comment: Add an `else` on the conditional so you know if it hits it or not.

Comment: @Achshar The `<?php` and `?>` would make an element so the code wouldn't be displayed unless viewing the source.

Comment: Crap, yeah correct.

Comment: My server is currently set to PHP 5.5

Comment: @chris85 I added an else statement and it didn't do either. So the PHP isn't being called as it should :/

Comment: I added
  <?php
  echo "Testing!";
  ?>

just inside the body tag and that didn't do anything either.

I also tried print "Testing!";

Comment: How are you accessing the file? What is the extension of the file? What do you see if you view the source?

Comment: @chris85 it is a .html file as everything on my site is done inside index.html

My site can be viewed here: http://itssimplytech.co.uk/

Comment: It needs to be `.php` or you need to make a handler.

Comment: View your source, you'll see the issue `<body id="body">
  <?php` PHP tags should never be exposed client side, if they are you have an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: @chris85 but my code don't show on screen :/ So how do I make this .php if it is full of html?

Comment: Change the name to `.php` it should still send the correct headers after it processes.

Comment: @chris85 I changed it to .php now the site does not work.

Comment: @chris85 https://gyazo.com/4cb0f6250ce176c7ed56eb3611754732

Comment: Your PHP has a syntax error somewhere. Check the error logs.

Comment: I can't find no error logs :?

Comment: @chris85 the only php in my code is the one shown in my original post. I removed all testing php code and still the same issue.

Comment: `$headers = 'From: '$email"\r\n".` is a syntax error. Needs to be ``$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n".``

Comment: @chris85 what is wrong with it?

Comment: You need to concatenate the variable to the strings. You could use double quotes, `$headers = "From: $email \r\n".` You need to figure out your error log location though. You **can't** code PHP without checking for errors.

Comment: @chris85 thank you that works now I have another problem XD